# How can I control the route to analyse with HyperLynx in a switch?

Tags: switches, signal-integrity, routing, hyperlynx

Good day to everyone.

I recently started using HyperLynx from Mentor and I'm having difficulties in analyzing the signal-integrity of the signals due to having switches in the circuit. 
When I load the IBIS of the switch, it detect correctly the different routes, but when I select the input route, it also selects all possible outputs.

In this case, the idea is to analyze the route from:

1) CLVTH16245 (bi-directional transceiver)  <- 2) SN74CBT16390DGGR (switch) <- 3) SN74CBT16214CDL (switch)

I select the line using right button and include in Analisys but it selects all the possible routes as you can see at the next image:
[image]

Moreover, when I try to modify the assigned model it doesn’t allow me to select only one route and select all three routes as you can see on second image.

[image]
Can anyone tell me how can I select only one route at a time to analyze?

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

As I found a solution to my own quiestion some time ago I would like to share it with everyone, as this may happen to many of us.

The solution was the modification of the IBIS file. In my project I was using different switches so I can tell you about different IBIS files. What I did was to force the IBIS model to work with only one route.

See the next capture where I show you the change in the IBIS file.

[image]

As you can see I deleted all the routes except the route 3. this allows me to study the route 3 of the switch. I did the same for route 2 and 1. 
In another IBIS file of a different switch I had to do more modifications, so you have to be careful when doing this.

Also some IBIS models aren't correct so the simulation can still give problems.

In sum, it's a slow process but at least it works.

Best regards.